# Take MySQL backup

Tags: java, mysql, ioexception, sqlexception

I need to avoid the error and store database backup in separate file path using mysqldump

```
public class NewClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, SQLException {
        String dbName = "test";
        String dbUser = "root";
        String dbPass = "root";
        try {
            String executeCmd = "";
            executeCmd = "mysqldump -u " + dbUser + " -p" + dbPass + " " + dbName + " -r backup.sql";

            Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
            int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();

            if (processComplete == 0) {
                System.out.println("Backup taken successfully");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Could not take mysql backup");
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }    

    }
}
```

> ERROR:run:
>     Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mysqldump": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file
>   specified
>         at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1042)
>         at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:615)
>         at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:448)
>         at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:345)
>         at mypkg.NewClass.main(NewClass.java:27)
>       Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
>         at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.ProcessImpl.(ProcessImpl.java:288)
>         at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:133)
>         at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1023)
>         ... 4 more
>       Java Result: 1
>       BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: Is mysqldump in your OS path variable?

Comment: Is the `mysqldump` program on your `%PATH%` or `$PATH`?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the full path the mysqldump program

```
executeCmd = "/full/path/to/mysqldump -u " + dbUser + " -p" + dbPass + " " + dbName + " -r backup.sql";
```

I'd also be tempted to put the full path the file where the dump is to be written as well.

Comment: Hi DaveHowes, this line error: executeCmd = "C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.1\\bin\\mysqldump -u " + dbUser + " -p" + dbPass + " " + dbName + " -r backup.sql";

Comment: Hi DaveHowes, can you see this link my modified coding  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758634/store-database-backup

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to give the exec function a String-array? This helped me some time ago.

```
String[] comm = new String[4];
comm[0] = "C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.1\\bin\\mysqldump"
comm[1] = "-u " + dbUser;
comm[2] = "-p " + dbPass + " " + dbName;
comm[3] = "-r backup.sql";
Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(comm)
```

Because i had some strange behavior when using a single String as parameter ...

Answer (score 0):

Simply modify your

```
executeCmd = "mysqldump -u " + dbUser + " -p" + dbPass + " " + dbName + " -r backup.sql";
```

to

```
executeCmd = "mysqldump -u " + dbUser + " -p" + dbPass + " " + dbName;
```

and add after if-else statement

```
String str="";

PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("path for this file/backup.sql");

Scanner outScanner = new Scanner(runtimeProcess.getInputStream());

while(outScanner.hasNextLine()){

pw.println(outScanner.nextLine());

}

outScanner.close();

pw.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. For me I just added the mysql in the path variable. An old installation was set in path variable. Removed it and add the new path.